# Page loading is slow in MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I have developed application in MVC using rojar view.it working fine but one of testing server rander the page in 4 seconds and on production server it takes 30-35 seconds.

Database on both the server are different nut code and number of records are same on both the server

```
foreach (var subcategpory in Model.category.RFP_SubCategories)
 {
     if (subcategpory.RFP_Questions.Any(q => q.SubCategoryId == subcategpory.SubCategoryId))
     {
 <div class="vendor-block">
     <div class="vendor-title border-bottom">
         <h6>@subcategpory.SubCategory</h6>
         <p>Selected:<span class="selectedQuestion" id="selectedQuestion_@subcategpory.SubCategoryId">0</span></p>
     </div>
     <ul class="vendor-list">
         @if (Model.category.RFP_Questions != null)
         {
             foreach (var que in subcategpory.RFP_Questions.Where(q => q.SubCategoryId == subcategpory.SubCategoryId))
             {
                 bool IsChecked = Model.category.RFP_SelectedQuestions.Any(sq => sq.QuestionId == que.QuestionId);
            }
         }
     </ul>
 </div>   
     }
 }
```

Can you please suggest any way to resolve the issue and actual reason.

Thanks,
Vishal

Answer (score 0):

I would check that you have the same indexes on both databases as possibly there has been an index created on the test server which is missing on the live one.

Another obvious point would be that the live server may have more resource contention due to other things accessing the server. This situation could also be remedied by having correct indexes allowing the query to complete quickly.

I would check the `SubCategoryId` and `QuestionId` fields have appropriate indexes.

You could also look at the **statistics** and ensure they are up-to-date on the live server. This: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173804.aspx may be worth looking at.

Comment: QuestionId  is clustered index and SubCategoryId is non clustered index.

Comment: As per our analysis it takes time in process of rendering data. in the view. is there any way to speed up the prodess

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid deferred execution. Try this:

Don't use `Model.category.RFP_SubCategories` directly.Instead:

```
var lst=Model.category.RFP_SubCategories.ToList()
```

and loop through using `lst`

You can also change

```
         foreach (var que in subcategpory.RFP_Questions.Where(q => q.SubCategoryId == subcategpory.SubCategoryId))
         {
             bool IsChecked = Model.category.RFP_SelectedQuestions.Any(sq => sq.QuestionId == que.QuestionId);
         }
```

to

```
var qstnsList= subcategpory.RFP_Questions.Where(q => q.SubCategoryId == subcategpory.SubCategoryId).ToList()
```

and use `qstnsList` in `foreach` loop if data exist.
Try this and do tell me if it saved time or not.

Comment: Applied the changes but not effect in execution time.

Comment: As per our analysis it takes time in process of rendering data. in the view. is there any way to speed up the prodess